# WHat is wrong with my angular code?

Tags: angularjs

```
<body>
<div data-ng-controller="itemController as store">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" data-ng-repeat="product in store.product.names">
            <h3>{{store.product.name}}
                <em class="pull-right">{{store.product.price}}</em>
        </h3>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('store', []);
    app.controller('itemController', function($scope) {
        $scope.product = gem;
    });

    var gem = [{
        name: 'Item1',
        price: 15
    }, {
        name: 'Item2',
        price: 16
    }, {
        name: 'Item3',
        price: 17
    }, {
        name: 'Item4',
        price: 18
    }, {
        name: 'Item5',
        price: 19
    }];
})();
</script>
<!-- <script src="jquery.js"></script>-->
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

After viewing the page on my browser and checked the console page, i received this error message

Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'itemController' is not a function, got undefined.

Comment: You should define variable before using OR assigning it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not use product.names with ng-repeat.

Try Below Code :

```
<body>
<div data-ng-controller="itemController as store">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" data-ng-repeat="product in products">
            <h3>{{product.name}}
                {{product.price}}
        </h3>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('store', []);
    app.controller('itemController', function($scope) {
        $scope.products = gem;
    });

    var gem = [{
        name: 'Item1',
        price: 15
    }, {
        name: 'Item2',
        price: 16
    }, {
        name: 'Item3',
        price: 17
    }, {
        name: 'Item4',
        price: 18
    }, {
        name: 'Item5',
        price: 19
    }];
})();
</script>
<!-- <script src="jquery.js"></script>-->
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your ng-repeat like this,

```
<div data-ng-controller="itemController">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" data-ng-repeat="product in products">
            <h3>{{product.product.name}}
                <em class="pull-right">{{product.price}}</em>
        </h3>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('store', []);
    app.controller('itemController', function($scope) {
     var gem = [{
        name: 'Item1',
        price: 15
    }, {
        name: 'Item2',
        price: 16
    }, {
        name: 'Item3',
        price: 17
    }, {
        name: 'Item4',
        price: 18
    }, {
        name: 'Item5',
        price: 19
    }];
        $scope.products = gem;
    });  
})
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/J3pcGv0q8OUrBIPIm984?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

This is your working code - [In thin plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CMhbaFoRX3eHnzDc1xUR?p=preview)

*HTML CODE:*

```
<div data-ng-controller="itemController">
      <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item" data-ng-repeat="item in product">
              <h3>{{item.name}}
              <em class="pull-right">{{item.price}}</em>
          </h3>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

*In controller:*

// Code goes here

```
(function(){
   var app = angular.module('store', []);
    app.controller('itemController', function($scope) {
      $scope.hello = 'hello';
        var gem = [{
            name: 'Item1',
            price: 15
        }, {
            name: 'Item2',
            price: 16
        }, {
            name: 'Item3',
            price: 17
        }, {
            name: 'Item4',
            price: 18
        }, {
            name: 'Item5',
            price: 19
        }];
        $scope.product = gem;
    });
})();
```